# trigger and dblink

Tags: postgresql

im working on a trigger in PL/TCL that inserts data into tableB on databaseB upon insertion on tableA from databaseA. both databases are on the same server. i came up with this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_to_erp() RETURNS trigger AS $$  
BEGIN  
IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN  
perform dblink_connect('dbname=oerp_test user=postgres password=abouali');  
perform dblink_exec('insert into product_template(standard_price, list_price, name) 
values 
('||NEW.pricebuy||','||NEW.pricesell||','||NEW.name||');');  
perform dblink_exec('insert into product_product(product_tmpl_id) values (currval(''product_template_id_seq''::regclass));');  
perform dblink_disconnect();  
END IF;  
RETURN NEW;  
END; $$  
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';  
CREATE TRIGGER add_to_erp_trigger AFTER INSERT ON products FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
add_to_erp();
```

but when i try:

```
INSERT INTO products (id,reference,code,name,pricebuy,pricesell,category,taxcat) VALUES (3,3,3,'apple',12,24,'000','000');
```

i get:

> ERROR: column "apple" does not exist

if i try instead:

```
INSERT INTO products (id,reference,code,name,pricebuy,pricesell,category,taxcat) VALUES (3,3,3,'34',12,24,'000','000');
```

its successful

Any ideas on the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the quotes on the value for the name column in the query you're constructing.  You'll need:

```
perform dblink_exec('insert into product_template(standard_price, list_price, name) 
                     values ('||NEW.pricebuy||','||NEW.pricesell||','''||NEW.name||''');');
```

Where `''` within the string becomes `'`, then you concatenate `apple`, so the end result becomes `values (12,24,'apple')` instead of `values (12,24,apple)`